# Return to previous page and refresh it in php?

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I have a submit form and while submitting the form it will load a php for the process like insert to DB and all.For going back to the submit form I 
added

```php
 header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

But how to reload the page (the submit form page so user can see the submitted form details)

Comment: You can't just reload the page and have information on form appear magically. When the page loads, check if data exists in the database, and if it does, pre-populate the form.

Comment: Surely in the form you could put `action=""` so that the form posts to itself, then do a check isset on the post and insert into the db. Fill all the form fields to have a value of their posted values. This way they submit the form, the values stay in the fields and on insert you can simply put a success message. You could even do a check on the field if the posted value is set and if so, disable the input so it cannot be resubmitted

Comment: PHP function `header()` only sends HTTP header to a browser.
You need not to send any headers. You need to generate new HTML-page with form populated with submitted data.
To do this you can use the same PHP script that generates page with bare form but put the submitted data in appropriate fields in HTML.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to paste here your code and exact problem. Now you are looking for solution that will do some work, not solve some concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try redirecting to previous page
redirectin will cause the browser to make a new http request refreshing the page content
to get the previous page address you can use HTTP_REFERER

```
$previousPage = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
header('Location: '.$previousPage);
```

this will cause the browser to re-navigate to the previous page

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="text" name="surname" value="<?php echo $_POST["surname"]; ?>" <?php echo (empty($_POST['surname']) ? "" : "disabled='true'"); ?>>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       //insert to db
       echo "success";
    }
?>
```

Comment: It is fine method. But used this and problem solved                 $previousPage = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
        header('Location: '.$previousPage);             Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

After submit the form data, you should check data exist or not. 
if exist you would be fetch data from Database & render the view file.

Something like

```
function somthing() {
    if($_POST[]) {
        // inser data into DB
        // then
        // fetch last inserted row from DB
        render view file with fetched row values
    }

    render view file without  fetched row values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a proper way to show data to user. you have to create separate forms to submit values & show the values on html. each time when user click on it the sql query run & show related data.